# GWT AsyncCallback not returning to client

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, callback, rpc

So I have a problem receiving back an RPC call from my second app module. Whatever callback I use, whatever parameters I pass along, the call will always be processed to the very end server-side, but not fire onSuccess or onFailure. It is guaranteed, that the method server-side is executed and returning a valid value. The call seems to just vanish because there´s also no error appearing.

My read is that there is an error in the module structure then maybe?

Here is the code of the class / view that I am starting the RPC call from:

```
package de.hdm.reportgenerator.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ScrollPanel;

import de.hdm.core.client.ClientsideSettings;
import de.hdm.core.shared.AdministrationServiceAsync;
import de.hdm.core.shared.ReportGeneratorAsync;
import de.hdm.core.shared.bo.Profile;
import de.hdm.core.shared.bo.SearchProfile;
import de.hdm.core.shared.report.HTMLProfilesReport;

public class AllProfilesView extends UpdateReportGenerator {

private SearchProfile searchProfile = new SearchProfile();
private Boolean unseenChecked = null;

private ReportGeneratorAsync reportGenerator = ClientsideSettings.getReportGenerator();
private AdministrationServiceAsync adminService = ClientsideSettings.getAdministration();

private ScrollPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();

HTML verLine = new HTML("  <table style='display:inline;border-collapse:collapse;border:0'><tr><td style='padding:0'><img src='transparent.gif' width='1' height='500' style='background:grey'></td></tr></table>"); 

HTML horLine = new HTML("<hr  style=\"width:100%;\" />");

Logger logger = ClientsideSettings.getLogger();

public AllProfilesView (Boolean unseenChecked, SearchProfile searchProfile){

    logger.info("Zeile 33 APV ausgeführt");
    this.searchProfile = searchProfile;
    this.unseenChecked = unseenChecked;
    logger.info("Zeile 37 APV ausgeführt");
}

/**
 * Jeder Showcase besitzt eine einleitende �berschrift, die durch diese
 * Methode zu erstellen ist.
 * 
 * @see Showcase#getHeadlineText()
 */
// @Override
protected String getHeadlineText() {
    return "Show Report - generated";
}

/**
 * Jeder Showcase muss die <code>run()</code>-Methode implementieren. Sie
 * ist eine "Einschubmethode", die von einer Methode der Basisklasse
 * <code>ShowCase</code> aufgerufen wird, wenn der Showcase aktiviert wird.
 */
@Override
protected void run() {

    //adminService.searchAndCompareProfiles(unseenChecked, searchProfile, comparedProfilesCallback());
    reportGenerator.testCallback(testCallback());

    logger.info("Zeile 61 ausgeführt");
    scrollPanel.add(horLine);
    RootPanel.get("Details").add(scrollPanel);
    scrollPanel.setSize("100%", "100%");

    logger.info("Zeile 66 ausgeführt");

}

private AsyncCallback<ArrayList<Profile>> comparedProfilesCallback() {
    AsyncCallback<ArrayList<Profile>> asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<Profile>>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            ClientsideSettings.getLogger().severe("Error: " + caught.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<Profile> result) {

            System.out.println("Zeile 85 APV ausgeführt");
            scrollPanel.add(HTMLProfilesReport.generateAllProfilesReport(result));
            System.out.println("Line 87 APV executed");

        }
    };
    return asyncCallback;
} 

private AsyncCallback<Integer> testCallback() {
    AsyncCallback<Integer> asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            ClientsideSettings.getLogger().severe("Error: " + caught.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Zeile 100 APV ausgeführt");

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Integer result) {

            System.out.println("Line 107 APV executed");

        }
    };
    return asyncCallback;
} 

}
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

<!-- Servlets -->

<servlet>

    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>

        <param-name>services</param-name>
        <param-value />

    </init-param>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>administrationService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.hdm.core.server.AdministrationServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>administrationService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/editor/administration</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/reportgenerator/administration</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>reportgenerator</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.hdm.core.server.ReportGeneratorImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>reportgenerator</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/reportgenerator/reportgenerator</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>

    <servlet-name>loginService</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>de.hdm.core.server.LoginServiceImpl</servlet-class>

</servlet>



<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>loginService</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/editor/login</url-pattern>

    <url-pattern>/reportgenerator/login</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Editor.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And here is the modules gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit     2.7.0//EN" "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='reportgenerator'>
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<inherits name="de.hdm.core.Core" />
<!-- Logger implementieren -->
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINEST" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler"
    value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.hasWidgetsHandler" value="ENABLED" />

<!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet. You can change -->
<!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting -->
<!-- any one of the following lines. -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean' />
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/> -->

<!-- Other module inherits -->

<!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
<entry-point class="de.hdm.reportgenerator.client.ReportgeneratorEntryPoint" />


<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
<source path='client' />
<source path='server' />
<source path='shared' />

<!-- allow Super Dev Mode -->
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />

</module>
```

I hope you might be able to help me and that I have included every information necessary to understand.

Sincerely
Phil

Comment: You have `System.out` calls in your callback, but browser's don't have stdout or stderr. Have you tested using some other form of logging that a browser _does_ support - you have console logging enabled, or creating a popup like `Window.alert`.

Comment: Works like a charm.. thank you Colin...